# How can I find the values that are included in each of n arrays (Python)?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I'll preface this with saying that I'm new to Python, but not new to OOP.

I'm using `numpy.where` to find the indices in n arrays at which a particular condition is met, specifically if the value in the array is greater than x.

What I want to do is find the indicies in which all n arrays meet that condition - so in each each array, at index y, the element is greater than x.

```
n0[y] > x 
n1[y] > x
n2[y] > x
n3[y] > x
```

For example, if my arrays after using numpy.where were:

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b = [0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]
c = [0,2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23]
d = [0,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55]
```

I want to get the output
`[0,2]`

I found the function `numpy.isin`, which seems to do what I want for just two arrays. I don't know how to go about expanding this to more than two arrays and am not sure if it's possible.

Here's the start of my code, in which I generate the indices meeting my criteria:

```
n = np.empty([0])
n = np.append(n,np.where(sensor[i] > x)[0])
```

I'm a little stuck. I know I could create a new array with the same number of indicies as my original arrays and set the values in it to true or false, but that would not be very efficient and my original arrays are 25k+ elements long.

Comment: can you make this an example with input and expected output? It's hard to work on this problem without an example of `sensor` implying the `a,b,c,d` you provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the intersection of n different arrays, first convert them all to sets. Then it is possible to apply [`set.intersection()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection). For the example with `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`, simply do:

```
set.intersection(*map(set, [a,b,c,d]))
```

This will result in a set `{0, 2}`.

Comment: Excellent, this worked. For anyone in the future who faces this - I have a list of intersecting sets, where the first element is n0 converted into a set. The next element is the output of set.intersection(previous element, n1) such that the final index is the intersection of all the sets of indicies. I had to do it this way since I don't know how many inputs I'll have.

I then converted the end result back into a list using `overlap = list(sorted(agreement_sets[i]))` since I need the indicies to be in order for future operations.